# What certification do you need to sell electronic device to US market?

Tags: fcc, certification, ce

Other than FCC and RoHS statement, what other certifications do you need to have in order to sell your product to US Market?

My device is a remote control using Bluetooth Module. Operate using 4 x AA battery . 
The Bluetooth module is already certified with CE and FCC.

I was told I may need a Safety test. ETL if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: BTW, RoHS is a European directive that is not required in the US.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the device is deemed to be information technology equipment (which it may, since it uses Bluetooth) you would be under the '60950' standard - UL 60950, and if you want to cross the border into Canada, CSA C22.2 #60950 (the standards are largely identical, so it makes sense to get both).

[Intertek ETL](http://www.intertek.com/marks/etl/) is a US Nationally Recognized Testing Laboratory (NRTL) authorized to test to UL 60950. You could use UL, CSA, TUV, MET or any other NRTL to do the approval - it doesn't have to be Intertek.

The best way to know if the product needs approval is to get an opinion/quotation from an NRTL - they'll tell you what they believe the product needs and how much a certification will cost.

Comment: Thanks @Madmanguruman. How much is the UL test compare to FCC?

Comment: It's my understanding that UL investigations are in the tens of thousands, and subsequent updates (post-approval) are in the thousands. It depends on the scope of the work. Both places I've been have had an agreement with the regulatory agency to do witnessed testing, where a designated employee does most of the work and the representative witnesses some critical tests and does the paperwork.